# How can python + selenium + chromedriver use mouse wheel?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

There is a `<ul>`tag in a webpage, and so many `<li>` tags in the `<ul>` tag. The `<li>` tags are loaded by ajax automatically while mouse wheel scroll down continuously.

The loading of `<li>` tags will work well if I use mouse wheel.

I want to use selenium to get the loaded info in `<li>` tags, but the javascript of:

`document.getElementById(/the id of ul tag/).scrollTop=200;`

can not work as the new `<li>` can not be loaded by ajax neither in chrome console nor the selenium `execute_script`.

So, if there is an API of selenium to behave like mouse wheel scroll down? Or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From now on, there is not any reasonable reason, so I close this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at the ajax load event listener (the code that loads more `<li>`s).  You need to trigger whatever that listens for. (aka: does it watch for something entering the view port, or something's y-offset, or  a `MouseEvent`, or a `scroll()`?)

Then you need to trigger that kind of event on the element it listens to.